# Rails NewRelic Recording with Capistrano 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems, capistrano

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли при деплое через капистрано
выполнять

> before 'deploy:finished', 'newrelic:notice_deployment'

но что бы `license_key` брался не из моего локального `newrelic.yml`, а с продакшена

что бы я мог не имея на локальном компе  файла `newrelic.yml` делать деплой и выполнялся

> before 'deploy:finished', 'newrelic:notice_deployment'

Gemfile: `gem 'newrelic_rpm'`

Capfile: `require 'new_relic/recipes'`

```
#deproy.rb
set :linked_files, %w(config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/newrelic.yml)
set :newrelic_role, ['app']
before 'deploy:finished', 'newrelic:notice_deployment'
```

Лог

```
Unexpected error attempting to connect to rpm.newrelic.com:443
license_key was not set in newrelic.yml for production: /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/cli/commands/deployments.rb:84:in `run'
   /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/recipes/capistrano3.rb:55:in `send_deployment_notification_to_newrelic'
   /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/recipes/capistrano3.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
   /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
   /Users/lutsko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@cargoport/gems/sshkit-1.11.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
00:00 newrelic:notice_deployment
      license_key was not set in newrelic.yml for production
```

Comment: Мда, там действительно дурацкая ситуация. В идеале, `notice` надо слать по SSH с сервера, но похоже, что означенный таск для Капистрано работает локально.

Comment: может кто-то встречал нормальный рецепт для капистрано, который бы решил мою проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем для решения моей задачи, мне пришлось написать такс, так как готового решения я не нашел.
Может кому-то пригодится

```
namespace :new_relic do
  desc 'Uploaded deployment information to New Relic'
  task :notice_deployment do
    run_locally do
      local_config_path = Pathname.new('tmp')
      ENV['NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_PATH'] = "#{local_config_path}/newrelic.yml"

      system "scp -P 9999 username@host:#{deploy_to}/shared/config/newrelic.yml #{local_config_path}"
      invoke 'newrelic:notice_deployment'
      system "rm -r #{local_config_path}/newrelic.yml"
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:finished', 'new_relic:notice_deployment'
```

Если есть предложения как сделать лучше, напишите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [исходному коду](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/5c871f4e2c55970ff3f5a8ae3b0eda8b094a1df3/lib/new_relic/recipes/capistrano3.rb#L12):

```
if fetch(:newrelic_role)
  on roles(fetch(:newrelic_role)) do
    send_deployment_notification_to_newrelic
  end
else
  run_locally do
    send_deployment_notification_to_newrelic
  end
end
```

У вас просто не задан `:newrelic_role`. Там должен быть массив ролей с NewRelic, а-ля:

```
set :newrelic_role, ['app']
```

*(Не очень понятно, почему ключ в единственном числе; может и одна роль сработает.)*

Comment: так я уже пробовал, без толку
`Unexpected error attempting to connect to rpm.newrelic.com:443
license_key was not set in newrelic.yml for production: `

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко значит, выясните, выполняет ли он его по-прежнему локально, или на продакшене действительно в этот момент этого файла нет.

Comment: ну судя по бектрейсу он локально проходит через `run_locally`

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко ну, магии не бывает. Либо у вас действительно не задан `:newrelic_role`, либо у вас другая версия этих рецептов. Какая, кстати?

Comment: newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326

Comment: `set :newrelic_role, :app` стоит

судя по https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/pull/231 это правильно

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко да не, [там то же самое](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/f856c5173b3ab5875161d2bcba6dea9f466a29d7/lib/new_relic/recipes/capistrano3.rb#L10-L21).

Comment: ну в любом случае и `set :newrelic_role, ['app']` я тоже пробовал

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко добавьте в вопрос детали об ошибке, будем думать.